# No broadcast completed INSTALL_REFERRER

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, install-referrer

I'm trying to have install referrer on my android app, but failed for something.

I need to receive variables when someone download/install my app form appstore. So I install a cordova plugin, android-referrer-plugin, into my app. And then try it:

`adb shell`

and then

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER \
-n com.mypackage.app/com.eightz.mobile.cordova.plugin.android.referrer.Receiver \
--es "referrer" "This is my referrer"
```

And then I've got a response like this:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=com.mypackage.app/com.eightz.mobile.cordova.plugin.android.referrer.Receiver (has extras) }
```

And that's it.. I don't see

```
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

I'm not sure if it's long loading for something or what, but I never see this line, and I cannot further on.
I check if I can get the variable, but I just got empty variable. No error though..

Could someone point my mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

```
Did you regsiter broadcast receiver in manifest. Did you set intent filter to that receiver in manifest too. 

<receiver android:name="com.mobileapptracker.Tracker" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes.. it's a cordova plugin and I use adobe pgb, but this should be in the manifest xml file. `<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.eightz.mobile.cordova.plugin.android.referrer.Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: Hello  @Prateek Bharadwaj Can you please let me know how can i put a value by using this       ADB and Fastboot>adb shell am broadcast -a package_name.sp.PUT --es key long --es value "9223372036854775807"
Broadcasting: Intent { act=package_name.sp.PUT (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0

Comment: Actually I am getting issue